# IIS Optimization

Tags: iis, performance, optimization

What kind of optimization (performance or whatever) do you use when going live with IIS (on windows 2003) ?

Currently, I use 1 application pool per web site, but I think I can do more :)

Comment: I tend to think about giving the images and css directory their own pool also as it just keeps active processing separate from file serving

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even on large banks, I've rarely (can't remember when) done any optimizations on IIS that weren't just the addition of modules. I keep all the defaults.

- Dynamic and Static Compression
- Set Expires dates on Static content, images, JS, etc

Answer (score 2):

Why would you consider using a single app pool per website as an optimization? Separating websites into different app pools should only be done if you have an explicit need for it like:

- Different .NET versions
- Different identity requirements
- Crashing websites
- Recycle schedules
- Etc

Comment: Crashing website : check. I have an old application (isapi module), that keeps crashing. Needs manually restarting the application pool :) I'm glad we've 1 apppool per website.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good articles on TechNet:

- [Top Ten Ways To Pump Up IIS
  Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.11.pumpupperformance.aspx)
- [Performance Tuning (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/71490aae-f444-443c-8b2a-520c2961408e.mspx?mfr=true)
- [Optimizing IIS 6.0 Performance (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/01cb5312-c8d0-48b5-955a-47b61fccff04.mspx?mfr=true)
- [Performance Tuning
  Guidelines for Windows Server
  2003](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/evaluation/performance/tuning.mspx)  (covers IIS 6 as a workload)
- [Performance Tuning Guidelines for
  Windows Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysperf/Perf_tun_srv.mspx) (covers IIS 7 as a workload)

Answer (score 1):

You should see what your score is in [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/). We run that on all sites before they deploy. A few tips:

1. [Minify](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/) your JS and combine it into one JS file (put that reference at the bottom of the html file).
2. Combine your CSS into one file.
3. Enable GZIP and deflate compression. Add .js and .css to the type of files it will compress. [ZIPEnable](http://www.port80software.com/products/zipenable/) is good for this.
4. Set up content expiration for 1 year. Remember that if you modify a css/js/image file after you do this, you will need to rename that file and update references so clients pull the latest version.
5. [Disable E-Tags](http://www.jesscoburn.com/archives/2008/10/02/quickly-configure-or-disable-etags-in-iis7-or-iis6/).