# Can I improve overall IIS performance by moving my heavily used pages to a separate app pool?

Tags: iis, performance, iis-6, asp.net

This is related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/89/iis-optimization), but I believe my situation is more specific.  I have a website on IIS 6.0, Windows Server 2003, that is running extremely slowly across the board.  All the pages have slowed down, though most of the traffic is centered around one page.  The job of that page is to upload files on to the web server, and a ton of files are being uploaded to the server every day.

Just because all these files are being uploaded, doesn't mean my login page has to be slow right?  I'm thinking if I moved the upload page to a separate virtual directory/app pool, the rest of the website would speed up.  What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the app pool would not make any difference in performance.
App pools are mostly used for security isolation. You can try to put the pages on separate disks so you can do more IO operations.
(based on school knowledge)